# How to inject javascript into uiwebview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I looked at a lot of the documentation from apple but I still can't seem to grasp the general idea of how to implement my javascript function into the webview.

I have an url:https://mobilemy.umd.edu/portal/server.pt/gateway/PTARGS_0_340574_368_211_0_43/https%3B/www.sis.umd.edu/testudo/studentSched?term=201401

I want to use javascript to fill in the form (username and password) and submit the forms.

In the console, I've been using the script:

```
javascript:(function() {
    document.lform.in_tx_username.value='username';
    document.lform.in_pw_userpass.value='password';
    doLogin();
    })()
```

Obj-c code look something like this:

```
loginScript = @"function() {document.lform.in_tx_username.value='username';
    document.lform.in_pw_userpass.value='password'; 
    doLogin();}";
[_visibleWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:scheduleURL]]];
[_visibleWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loginScript];
```

where scheduleUrl is the url i linked above.
I am pretty new to both Obj-C and JS so any help/tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` you are running the javascript on the page / HTML. You're passing in a function, which when evaluated will do nothing, because the function will not be called anywhere. Just run the javascript itself like so:

```
loginScript = @"document.lform.in_tx_username.value='username';
    document.lform.in_pw_userpass.value='password'; 
    doLogin();";
```

This javascript will get executed on the page instead of just being validated

Comment: do i still call the stringbyevaluating: function?

Comment: @CoderNinja yes thats how you pass it into the webview, the issue was you were passing a function which needs to be called rather than executable code

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the code when the webview's loading is finished:

load the request:

```
_visibleWebView = self;
[_visibleWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:scheduleURL]]];
```

then the inject the javascript call:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    loginScript = @"function() {document.lform.in_tx_username.value='username';
    document.lform.in_pw_userpass.value='password'; 
    doLogin();}";

    [_visibleWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loginScript];

}
```

EDIT

as Simon McLoughlin says, 
you also have to call the javascript method not only "declare" it